# React Native Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

why when i install react-native-maps, then i run it on android in command line an error appear like this.

Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.

> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: C:\Users\cak robet\Documents\react-native\Emergency\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\3.jar, C:\Users\cak robet\Documents\react-native\Emergency\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\4.jar, C:\Users\cak robet\Documents\react-native\Emergency\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\5.jar, C:\Users\cak robet\Documents\react-native\Emergency\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\6.jar, C:\Users\cak robet\Documents\react-native\Emergency\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\7.jar, C:\Users\cak robet\Documents\react-native\Emergency\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\8.jar, C:\Users\cak robet\Documents\react-native\Emergency\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\9.jar, C:\Users\cak robet\Documents\react-native\Emergency\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\10.jar, C:\Users\cak robet\Documents\react-native\Emergency\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\11.jar, C:\Users\cak robet\Documents\react-native\Emergency\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\12.jar, C:\Users\cak robet\Documents\react-native\Emergency\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\13.jar, C:\Users\cak robet\Documents\react-native\Emergency\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\14.jar, C:\Users\cak robet\Documents\react-native\Emergency\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\15.jar, C:\Users\cak robet\Documents\react-native\Emergency\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\16.jar, C:\Users\cak robet\Documents\react-native\Emergency\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\17.jar, C:\Users\cak robet\Documents\react-native\Emergency\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\18.jar, C:\Users\cak robet\Documents\react-native\Emergency\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\19.jar, C:\Users\cak robet\Documents\react-native\Emergency\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\20.jar, C:\Users\cak robet\Documents\react-native\Emergency\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\21.jar, C:\Users\cak robet\Documents\react-native\Emergency\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\22.jar, C:\Users\cak robet\Documents\react-native\Emergency\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\23.jar, C:\Users\cak robet\Documents\react-native\Emergency\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\24.jar, C:\Users\cak robet\Documents\react-native\Emergency\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\25.jar, C:\Users\cak robet\Documents\react-native\Emergency\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\26.jar, C:\Users\cak robet\Documents\react-native\Emergency\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\27.jar, C:\Users\cak robet\Documents\react-native\Emergency\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\28.jar, C:\Users\cak robet\Documents\react-native\Emergency\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\29.jar, C:\Users\cak robet\Documents\react-native\Emergency\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\30.jar, C:\Users\cak robet\Documents\react-native\Emergency\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\31.jar, C:\Users\cak robet\Documents\react-native\Emergency\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\65.jar, C:\Users\cak robet\Documents\react-native\Emergency\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\100.jar, C:\Users\cak robet\Documents\react-native\Emergency\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\104.jar, C:\Users\cak robet\Documents\react-native\Emergency\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\108.jar, C:\Users\cak robet\Documents\react-native\Emergency\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\112.jar, C:\Users\cak robet\Documents\react-native\Emergency\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\116.jar, C:\Users\cak robet\Documents\react-native\Emergency\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\120.jar, C:\Users\cak robet\Documents\react-native\Emergency\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\124.jar

Answer (score 0):

If there is any library used in project that have 
implementation `com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:+`
must be changed to specific version 
implementation `com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.0.0`

Eg: react-native-device-info